# jquery - how to check if the parent element is tbody or thead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I need to check whether a parent is a tbody or thead tag.

I have this right now, which does not work:

```
item.parent("thead")[0] = "<thead>" ? console.log("yes") : console.log("no");
```

Doesn't work though.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify whether you are looking for the direct parent or just checking to see if the `item` is contained within the `thead` or `tbody`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think this will work:

```
console.log(item.parent("thead").is("thead") ? "Yes" : "No");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G9LJT/0/ - No

http://jsfiddle.net/G9LJT/1/ - Yes

...

`item.parent("thead")[0]` refers to the first DOM element of your selector.

Comment: `parent("thead")` come back empty if there isn't a `thead`, so why bother using `is`?

Comment: instead of `is()` you could just check the `length` property to see if any elements were selected: `if (item.parent("thead").length > 0) {...}`

Comment: @Jasper that's exactly what I answered; you also don't need the `> 0` in JS.

Comment: @Mathletics I can't say it's totally logical but I don't like to use `truthy`/`falsy` comparisons.

Comment: @Jasper to each his own, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.is` as follows:

```
var isthead = item.parent().is("thead") ? "yes" : "no";
```

Note that `.is` returns `true` if any of the elements in the set matches, so you need `.first` to only test on the first element.

Comment: parent only returns one element; why use `first`?

Comment: @Mathletics you're right that he doesn't need first here, but parent can actually return as many elements as you feed it since each one could have a unique parent.

Comment: @Sinetheta I am (perhaps wrongly) assuming that `item` is a single element.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a anscestor `thead` tag and check it's `length` property to see if it exists:

```
item.parents("thead:first").length > 0 ? console.log("yes") : console.log("no");
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/upxyB/

Notice that I used the `:first` pseudo-selector to only get the first match since `parents()` is capable of returning a set of results (for instance if you have nested tables).

On a side-note, `item.parent("thead")[0] = "<thead>"` will always return true, you need double equals signs for a comparison operator: `item.parent("thead")[0] == "<thead>"`

Docs for comparison operators - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: This only checks if there is a `thead` ancestor, not if it is the actual parent.

Comment: @Mathletics I don't know what `item` is so I posted code that will work no matter what level the element is nested at. So your statement is totally true.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a DOM element to a string. You just need to check if the parent is what you want it to be by trying to select and checking the length:

```
item.parent('thead').length ? console.log('YES') : console.log('NO');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var item = $("#something");

if (item.parent().get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === 'thead') 
    alert('parent is thead'); 
else 
    alert('parent is not thead');
```

It should work with ie6+, ff, chrome/safari.

Comment: Note that `tagName` returns a capitalized tag name.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to post the details... tagName returns a capitalized tag name in HTML documents. In XHTML documents the tag case is preserved. Added .toLowerCase() to the answer.